# Construct URL depending on user choice AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a website that basically shows specific data from JSON files in a table.

**My issue is that I'll have over 250 potential different JSON files that could be loaded depending on the user choice**. For example, if the user clicks on the button "a" and then the button "b" it will need to load the file "a_b.json". For now I've tested with one json file, here is my test code:

```
var app = angular.module('webStatistics', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/stats/views/', {templateUrl: 'home'})
        .when('/stats/views/home.html', {
            controller : 'testController'
            templateUrl: '/stats/views/home.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});
});
app.controller('testController', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('../app/sources/stats/004/a_b.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.variables = data;
      });
});
```

**I would like to know if there is a way to "dynamically construct" the URL that I give to my $http service**? So if user's choice is x and option z ->../stats/x/x_z.json

Only one file will be loaded at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help.

```
var app = angular.module('webStatistics', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/stats/views/', {templateUrl: 'home'})
        .when('/stats/views/home.html', {
            controller : 'testController'
            templateUrl: '/stats/views/home.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});
});
app.controller('testController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.item1 = '';
    $scope.item2 = '';

    $scope.getData() {

        if ($scope.item1 && $scope.item2) {
            var api = '../app/sources/stats/004/' + item1 + '_' + item2 + '.json';
            $http.get(api).success(function(data) {
                $scope.variables = data;
            });
        }

    };
});
```

Comment: Figured out by the time, but thanks your code seems more optimized than mine :)